# REST API - How to modify email notifications in DocuSign request

Tags: docusignapi

How do you add reminders and expirations? I can CreateAndSend an envelope, but not sure where to add this optional parameter. My current JSON request below:

```
 POST https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/175597/envelopes

 {
     "emailBlurb": "Please sign to complete the document signature",
     "emailSubject": "Reminder and Expiration Test",
     "documents": [
         {
             "documentId": "1",
             "name": "7805dda0-9363-11e3-a6ef-0e26cd4d7860.pdf"
         }
     ],
     "recipients": {
         "signers": [
             {
                 "recipientId": "1",
                 "email": "email@hotmail.com",
                 "name": "Test Test",
                 "routingOrder": 1
             }
         ]
     },
     "status": "sent"
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the [CreateEnvelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/) API documentation

Here is an example that specifies the notification settings in the API request.

```
POST https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/175597/envelopes

{
 "emailBlurb": "Please sign to complete the document signature",
 "emailSubject": "Reminder and Expiration Test",
 "status": "sent",
 "documents" :[//dcouments go here],
 "recipients" :{//recipients go here},
 "notification":{ 
     "useAccountDefaults":"String content", 
     "reminders":{ 
         "reminderEnabled":"String content", 
         "reminderDelay":"String content", 
         "reminderFrequency":"String content" 
     }, 
     "expirations":{ 
         "expirationEnabled":"String content", 
         "expirationAfter":"String content", 
         "expirationWarn":"String content" 
     } 
   }
 }
```

Old documentation for the REST API can be found [here](https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/rest-api-guide-v2.pdf)

Comment: Note that the JSON on page 112 of the guide is INCORRECTLY formatted -- it includes brackets [ and ] for the reminders property and the expirations property.  In reality, the JSON should not include these brackets.  My answer shows the correct JSON format.

Comment: Thank you Kim! The issue was the brackets []. Your example works prefect and I noticed the documentation has been updated as well.