# how we can set reminders and expiration settings for docusign envelope from docusign rest api envelope?

Tags: docusignapi

how we can set reminders and expiration settings for docusign envelope from docusign rest api envelope ?

```
JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
/start notifications 
        gen.writeFieldName('notifications');       
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeStringField('useAccountDefaults', 'true');
         //start reminders   
        gen.writeFieldName('reminders');           
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeObjectField('reminderEnabled', 'true');
        gen.writeObjectField('reminderDelay', '1');
        gen.writeObjectField('reminderFrequency', '1');       
        gen.writeEndObject();      
         //end reminders 

         //start expiration    
        gen.writeFieldName('expirations');             
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeObjectField('expireEnabled', 'true');
        gen.writeObjectField('expireAfter', '7');
        gen.writeObjectField('expireWarn', '1');             
        gen.writeEndObject();       

         //end expiration 

        gen.writeEndObject();
         //end notifications
```

somehow these settings are not working.

Comment: This api call is invoked from apex language for salesforce.

Comment: This seems to be discussed in this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299085/rest-api-how-to-modify-email-notifications-in-docusign-request

Answer (score 1):

REST API Guide has a section on reminders and expirations. Here is a sample JSON:

```
notification":{ 
     "useAccountDefaults":"String content", 
     "reminders":{ 
         "reminderEnabled":"String content", 
         "reminderDelay":"String content", 
         "reminderFrequency":"String content" 
     }, 
     "expirations":{ 
         "expirationEnabled":"String content", 
         "expirationAfter":"String content", 
         "expirationWarn":"String content" 
     } 
}
```

https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST API References/Send an Envelope.htm?Highlight=reminders and expirations

Comment: A working code example is what people are looking for, my friend.